# Letting the user resize an image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, resize, imageview

Could anybody point me in the right direction on how to let the user resize an imageview by saying pinching dragging? I'm looking around but either searching for the wrong thing or just can't find anything on it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly popular library that does this already.  You can use it just like an ImageView:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView